# How to get the results of selection from a temporary table Ordered by a specific field?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, temp-tables

I mean how to reference specific columns in a temporary table in Oracle ?

Comment: A temporary table has named columns, so you just refer to those as you would with any permanent table. So I don't understand what you are asking. Maybe you're referring to a CTE or inline view, but the same applies.Or a table collection? Edit your question to explain what you mean, preferably with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following query sample is what you are expecting.

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS
( SELECT COLUMN_1,
COLUMN_2,
COLUMN_3
FROM TABLE_1)
SELECT TEMP_TABLE.COLUMN_1,
TEMP_TABLE.COLUMN_2
FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```

Cheers !!